# Yii extenstion for pdf generator uding template

Tags: yii, composer-php, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am looking for PDF generator extension/components for Yii 1.1.16.
This extension can be download using composer and can generate pdf from using html template .

Plz any one know can provide me link for that ??

Comment: Try these extensions
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/        or
            http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/529/create-generate-pdf-files-with-tcpdf-plugin-example-to-generate-table-with-tcpdf-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this following link and follow the given steps in that page http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/